# Flutter Getx, data from socket is only getting updated on ui when i open chatscreen for the first time

Tags: flutter, dart, socket.io, flutter-getx

Im using socket.io in flutter to implement a chatScreen, my messages are only updating lively when i enter any chatscreen for the first time. even though the data is getting added to the list . it's not getting reflected in the ui, when i send/recieve message after i close the same or any other chatScreen.

i have tried printing "chatList" after new messages arrive and the new messages are present in the list, but not updating.

note: When i enter a chatsScreen for the first time. its working fine, messages are sent and recieved and list update is reflected on ui . the issue happens when close and enter the chatscreen again.

here's my code

socketmanager.dart

```
class SocketManager {
  static IO.Socket? socket;
  static String channelRef = "";
  static List<String> channelRefList = [];
  static MessagesController messageScreenController =
  Get.find<MessagesController>();
  static ChatScreenController chatScreenController =
  Get.find<ChatScreenController>();
  // static BaseScreenController baseScreenController =
  // Get.find<BaseScreenController>();
  static void connectSocket() {
    print("connectSocket");
    if (user?.data.user.id == null) {
      print("USER NOT FOUND");
      return;
    }
    socket = IO.io(
        Config.socket,
        IO.OptionBuilder()
            .setTransports(['websocket']) // for Flutter or Dart VM
            .disableAutoConnect()
            .setExtraHeaders({
          "authorization":
          user?.data.user.id,
        })
            .setQuery(
            {
              "id": user?.data.user.id,
            })
            .enableForceNewConnection() // disable auto-connection
            .build());

    socket!.onConnect((_) {
      log("socket is connected");
      debugPrint(
          'socket connected ${user?.data.user.id}');
      // SocketManager.getMessagesListener();
    });
    socket!.onConnecting((data) => debugPrint("SOCKET onConnecting $data"));
    socket!.onConnectError((data) => debugPrint("SOCKET onConnectError $data"));
    socket!.onError((data) => debugPrint("SOCKET onError $data"));
    socket!.onDisconnect((data) => debugPrint("SOCKET onDisconnect $data"));
    socket!.connect();
  }

  static void socketDisconnect() {
    if (socket != null) {
      socket!.disconnect();
      socket!.onDisconnect((data) => debugPrint("onDisconnect $data"));
    }
  }

  static void disconnectChatListener(){
    if (socket != null){
      socket!.clearListeners();
    }
  }




  static void sendMessage(Map<String,String> message,) {
    // print("Emit sendMessage: ${message}");
    if (socket!.connected) {
      log("Emit Message: ${message}");
      socket!.emit('messageRequest', message);
    }
  }



  static void getMessagesListener() {
    log("{getMessagesListener}");
    SocketManager.socket!.on('messageResponse', (data) {
      debugPrint("GET message in socket $data");
      debugPrint("ChannelRef $channelRef");
      ChatsData newMsg = ChatsData.fromJson(data);
      if (newMsg.channelRef == channelRef) {
        updateMessageList(newMsg);
      }
      // updateChatList(newMsg);
    });
  }

  static void updateMessageList(ChatsData msg) {
    log("updateMessageList");
      print("HERE WE GOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");

    chatScreenController.getchatList.insert(0, msg);
    chatScreenController.isUpdateMessage = true;
    chatScreenController.updateChatList();
    chatScreenController.update();
      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2), () {
        chatScreenController.isUpdateMessage = false;
      });

  }
```

ChatscreenController.dart

```
class ChatScreenController extends GetxController {



  var chatsLoadingStatus = LoadingStatus.loading.obs;

  static MessagesController messageScreenController =
  Get.find<MessagesController>();

  


  List<ChatsData> getchatList = [];
  List<ChatsData> get chatList => getchatList;
  set chatList(List<ChatsData> value) {
    getchatList = value;
    update();
  }



  String? channelId = Get.arguments[0]['channelId'];
  String? userName = Get.arguments[1]['userName'];
  String? eventName = Get.arguments[2]['eventName'];
  String? receiverId = Get.arguments[3]['receiverId'];
  String? eventId  = Get.arguments[4]['eventId '];


  final count = 0.obs;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    SocketManager.channelRef = channelId ?? "";
    print("SOCKET MANAGER CHANNEL REF-----------------${SocketManager.channelRef}");
    SocketManager.getMessagesListener();
    fetchChatList();
    super.onInit();
  }

 


  void updateChatList(){
    log("======UPDATE CHAT");
    print('LAST MESSAGE=========== ${chatList.first.toJson().toString()}');
    update();
  }



  void fetchChatList() async {
    try {
      var accessToken = await Config.flutterSecureStorage.read(
        key: Config.userAccessToken,
      );
      final response = await APIProvider().postAPICall(
        APIConstants.listChat,
        {
          'channelRef': channelId,
        },
        {
          'Authorization': '$accessToken',
        },
      );
      if (response.data["code"] == 100) {
        List list = response.data["data"];
        getchatList = list.map((e) => ChatsData.fromJson(e)).toList();
        chatsLoadingStatus.value = LoadingStatus.completed;
        update();

      } else if (response.data["code"] == 101) {
        Get.back();
        Get.snackbar(
          'Failed',
          "Given Group not found",
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Get.back();
      Get.snackbar(
        'Failed',
        e.toString(),
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
      );
    }
  }




  @override
  void onClose() {
    log("-----------------DISCOONECT CHAT");
    SocketManager.disconnectChatListener();
    super.onClose();
  }




}
```

chatView.dart

```
class ChatScreenView extends GetView<ChatScreenController> {
  const ChatScreenView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var messageController = TextEditingController().obs;
    return Scaffold(
      ....
        body: GetBuilder(
          builder: (ChatScreenController controller){
          return Column(
            children: [
              controller.chatsLoadingStatus.value == LoadingStatus.loading
                  ? Expanded(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                strokeWidth: 5.w,
                                color: AppConstant.appDarkBlue,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : controller.chatList.isEmpty
                      ? Expanded(
                          child: Center(
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Center(
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        "No Chats Found!",
                                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                          fontSize: 20.sp,
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      : Expanded(
                          child: GroupedListView(
                            reverse: true,
                            elements: controller.chatList,
                            groupBy: (chats) => DateTime.now(),
                            groupHeaderBuilder: (ChatsData chats) => const SizedBox(),
                            itemBuilder: (context, ChatsData chats) {
                              return  Align(
                              alignment: chats.messageByMe == true
                                  ? Alignment.centerRight
                                  : Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                                child: BubbleNormal(
                                  bubbleRadius: 5,
                                  text: chats.message ?? "",
                                  tail: true,
                                  isSender: chats.messageByMe ?? false,
                                  color: chats.messageByMe == true
                                        ? AppConstant.appDarkBlue
                                        : AppConstant.appLightGray,
                                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: GoogleFonts.poppins().fontFamily,
                                    color:  chats.messageByMe == true
                                        ? Colors.white
                                        : Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );},
                          ),
                        ),
            ],
          );},
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I know getx is weak, but for some reasons. my company requires to use getx in all their projects.

Comment: Time to show your bosses that video.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Do you go around stackoverflow looking for getx question and asking each user to watch a video to ditch getx? I have seen your comment multiple times on different getx questions. Why don't you just answer the question rather than posting this video link?

Comment: @NadeemAmanah If hot reload, shows the new data then you are not setting the state when new chat data is coming in.

Comment: @Md.KamrulAmin because 90% of the time, either getx is obscuring the problem, or getx is itself the problem.  So I am doing the most effective answer to the problem, each and every time.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Getx Wasn't the problem, Problem was with initialisation of controllers, thank you.

Comment: @NadeemAmanah  can you please try  RxList for chat list